# Could not load type 'System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions' from assembly 'mscorlib

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm using Unity IoC (Microsoft.Practices.Unity) and I can compile fine, but I'm getting the following error at run time:

```
Could not load type 'System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

The Unity version is: 3.0.1026.0

Is there a compatibility problem between .Net 4 and this version of Unity. Also, I get the same error when using Unity v2. If so, how might I go about resolving this issue?

**EDIT:**
Also, I've verified that mscorlib is referenced in my project.

Comment: make sure your proj is .NET framework 4 and not 4 Client Profile

Comment: The taget framework for the web application is: .NET Framework 4

Comment: That's a .NET 4.5 class.  You didn't install and uninstall the dev preview for it, did you?

Comment: Hrmmmmm. I will check, give me a minute...

Comment: @Hans, that was it! Please give an answer, and I'll accept it!

Comment: Please post one yourself and accept it.  Knowing how to recover from it is the real answer.

Comment: @HansPassant: I m using 4.0 and i don't have 4.5.. so how can i fix this same issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**RESOLVED.**

Indeed I was using the .NET 4.5 preview version, which was referencing a class that didn't exist in my .NET 4.0 world. Thanks Hans Passant for the amazing speed in which you identified the problem!

Comment: Thanks for this! Took me a long time to figure out a very similar problem.. running 4.5 dll in 4.0