# VS 2019 C# - Use two versions of same package

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019

In my project I have a package A using System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe v>=5.0.0, and another package B using System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe v=4.5.3.

When I try to install System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe v=4.5.3 from the NuGet Package Manager I get the following error:

[Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe from 5.0.0 to 4.5.3. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6p0a.png)

I found information related to this issue at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605, where it is suggested to add a PackageReference of the needed version.

I tried to add reference for the 4.5.3 version or for both versions, yet nonE of these solutions seem to work.

Am I doing something wrong? How is it possible to use two different versions of the same package in one project?

Comment: .net 5 != .net 4.5 => upgrade all of your projects to support 5.0 or downgrade :)

Comment: Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67784313/2111137

Comment: Basically you can't use two different versions of the same package. It's unclear what your project structure is at the moment, which makes it hard to help you - but I'd expect that if you have a project C that relies on both A and B, it should be fine - it'll just use 5.0.0. (I'd expect that to be compatible with 4.5.3, as Microsoft *usually* avoids breaking changes in System packages, even across major versions.)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I am actually trying to use IronPython, which seems to need 4.5.3 as my code crashes trying to find: `'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1` (corresponding to v 4.5.3 as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764744/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe)