# web config <configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"> part caused error

Tags: azure-active-directory, webforms, json.net

I'm working on a very old web form application. We are modernizing it now and trying to use Azure active directory login page instead of our classic login page. When my web config file has this tag,

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

I get an error like this while running the project:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, 
Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its 
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly 
reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I get rid of this part of the configuration part and the problem solved.

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"
```

I searched on the net about this issue but couldn't find anything. Why this part is causing an error like this? Could someone explain it?

Comment: Check this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67784313/19648279) once.

Comment: Please do let me know the framework used in your old and new application.

Comment: Both are .NET FRAMEWORK 4.8. Framework have not been changed for this work. Only the login type changed.